# What is the relationship between Hattori and Yuujirou?

Tags: bakuman

In Season 1 Episode 22, during the KOOGY complaint scene, their full name was mentioned. Hattori Yuujirou and Hattori Akira. Are they siblings or mere coincidence that they share a surname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not stated in neither  Yuujirou's or Akira's Bakuman Wiki pages nor MAL pages   that they are siblings, the conclusion being that **they are not**. It may be a pure coincidence. I am not very informed regarding this anime though.

[Akira Hattori wiki page](http://bakuman.wikia.com/wiki/Akira_Hattori)

[Yuujirou Hattori wiki page](http://bakuman.wikia.com/wiki/Yujiro_Hattori)

also

[Akira Hattori MAL page](http://myanimelist.net/character/18914/Akira_Hattori)

[Yuujirou Hattori MAL page](http://myanimelist.net/character/23485/Yuujirou_Hattori)

As you can see their biographies do not say anything about them being blood-related in any way.

Also in **Akira Hattori's** wikipage it says:

> **Personal Status:**
>
> **Marital Status Single**
>
> **Relatives Unknown**
>
> **Education  Unknown**

If one of his relatives would have been mentioned (including Yuujiro) they would have been written in the wiki. Thus we conclude that they are not blood-related.

Moreover this quote:

> The editors in Bakuman are based off of real editors, so the names used just relate to the editors real names. The two aren't related.
>
> http://bakuman.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Yujiro_Hattori

shows that they are based on real editors and is a common thing in real life for 2 individuals to have the same family name and to not be blood-related.

Comment: Don't just post links. Summarize and quote key parts to make your point. How are we supposed to know what you're referring to if one or all of the links break?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ I always check the links I post in answers to be functioning but  they may break after I post them so I think it was  carelessly of me to base my answer only on them. I hope that my improved answer will be considered satisfactory by you and if it still has  flaws please feel free to tell me, in order to improve myself and my answers in the future.